# Install different version of npm packages in package.json conditionally

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, package.json

I'm developing a web app which uses a private package.
In some circumstances, I rather to use the local version of the package or different version of that package.

Is there any solution to indicate to use different version of package in package.json?

i.e:

`npm install --local`

while my package.json looks like:

```
...
"dependencies": { 
...
    "my_package": if(local) "address_to_local_package/" else "5.6.1"
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm` does not accommodate this (and honestly, probably should not). This seems like the type of thing that is usually handled at runtime via the `NODE_ENV` environment variable or similar mechanism. The module changes behavior depending on whether `NODE_ENV` is set to `"production"` or `"development"`. (But that's just convention. You can use values like `"local"` if you want.) So rather than installing different versions of the module, there's a single version that behaves differently based on the value of that environment variable.

If you really want different code bases installed entirely, it will take some effort but you can write a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#npm-install) script for `npm` to run. Your module then becomes nothing more than a script and then the `postinstall` figures out what to *actually* install based on environment variables or maybe a command line flag. This seems brittle to me, though. I'd think hard about if you're solving the right problem here if you go this route. `NODE_ENV` seems more elegant and conventional.